# Django Rest Framework add object with foreign key and depth = 1

Tags: django, rest

Using Django Rest Framework, I am attempting to add a model object via POST, specifying the id of an existing object to which the new object should have a foreign key. Works. If I add a depth=1 to the new object's serializer however, so that I get the foreign key target in a GET, the POST to add a new object fails with a mysql error 'IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'reportdefinition_id' cannot be null")', even though I specify a valid foreign key id in my POST.

I can work around this by leaving the depth = 1 out and retrieving the reportdefinition separately in my client, but that's cumbersome.

(I found two related questions, but neither answers mine:
[Django REST - Create object with foreign key using serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543775/django-rest-create-object-with-foreign-key-using-serializers)
[Need to show Foreign Key Object in Details by Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704719/need-to-show-foreign-key-object-in-details-by-django-rest-framework))

Models (I've not shown irrelevant fields):

```
class ReportDefinition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

class ReportRun(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    reportdefinition = models.ForeignKey(ReportDefinition)
```

Serializers:

```
class ReportDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = models.ReportDefinition
        fields = ("id","name")

class ReportRunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        depth = 1
        model = models.ReportRun
        fields =("id","status","reportdefinition")
```

If I remove 'depth = 1', the POST works.

```
class ReportRunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = models.ReportRun
        fields =("id","status","reportdefinition")
```

The POST contents (again, irrelevant other attributes not shown):

```
reportdefinition:1
```

One thing I noticed: without the depth = 1, the DRF browsable API shows "reportdefinition" in its default, but with depth = 1, it does not. I have to add it explicitly.

DRF browsable API content with depth = 1:

```
{
    "status": null,
}
```

(I add "reportdefinition": 1 when issuing the POST, and verify that it appears using Chrome Developer Tools)

DRF browsable API content with no 'depth = 1':

```
{
    "status": null,
    "reportdefinition": null
}
```

(I replace null with 1 when issuing the POST)

Answer (score 3):

The question is quite old but as nobody responded and as I had the same issue.

In fact, the response lies in the [release note](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#writable-nested-serialization) of version 3.0:

> If you define a depth, you now have to write your own create and
>   update methods that will handle the modification of the nested fields.

Link to [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).