# Creating an object with django rest api referencing a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Sorry if this has been asked, but I've dug through documentation and even a few other StackOverflow questions and none seem to solve my problem. I'm a bit new to Django, so sorry if this is answered somewhere else.

([Django REST - Create object with foreign key using serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543775/django-rest-create-object-with-foreign-key-using-serializers))
Just doing company_id as was suggested here did not work. Still not getting there.
Also tried the custom create function in the view as was suggested and no luck with that either.

I have a `Company` class with 2 values (id 1 and 2) and a `Project` class that contains a foreign key `company_id` back to `Company`. A `Project` must have exactly 1 `Company`.

Right now, I'm unable to do a POST to create a `Project`. I've tried referencing `company_id` specifically and even tried referencing nested serializers in the serializer. Nothing seems to work.

I'd probably prefer to send the `company_id` in POSTs and get back the referenced object when I GET. At this point though, I'd just be happy to get a POST to work. Note: The default `company_id` value is `1` so the first one I create will actually work. It's just that all subsequent POSTs end up giving this error:
`(1062, "Duplicate entry '1-RANDOM' for key 'project_project_company_id_key_007f87f8_uniq'")`

**Company**

```
# Model
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        unique=True
    )


# Serializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.company.models import Company

class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('url', 'company')


# View
from rest_framework import viewsets

from api.company.serializers import CompanySerializer
from api.company.models import Company


class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

**Project**

```
# Model
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

from api.company.models import Company


class Project(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_PK = 1

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('company', 'key'),)

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=DEFAULT_PK,
        blank=False
    )
    key = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        blank=False,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^[A-Z0-9\-]*$',
                message='Project key can only contain uppercase alphanumeric or a hythen (-)',
                code='invalid_key'
            ),
        ]
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=False
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True
    )


# Serializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.project.models import Project

from api.company.serializers import CompanySerializer


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #company = CompanySerializer(read_only=True) # Tried this to no avail.

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('url', 'key', 'name', 'description', 'company_id') # 'company' here did not work

# View
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from api.project.serializers import ProjectSerializer
from api.project.models import Project
from api.project.models import Company


class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

# Tried playing around with this from suggestion I find in other post. No luck
"""
def create(self, validated_data):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data)
    company_id_for_contact =  self.request.data.pop('company_id')
    company_instance = Company.objects.filter(id=company_id_for_contact).first()
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        print(serializer.errors)
    data = serializer.validated_data
    serializer.save(company=company_instance)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
"""
```

**Data**

```
# Note: the first one will work (default company_id is 1. Next one will not)
curl \
 -X POST \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{"company_id":2,"key":"OTHER","name":"Other","description":"Other example."}' \
'http://0.0.0.0:8000/project/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I should have held off 10 more minutes and I would have figured it out.
The curl POST needs `company`, not `company_id`. No `CompanySerializer` reference is needed in `Project`.

We just need to reference the `url` `(http://0.0.0.0:8000/company/2/)` since I'm using a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

Hopefully someone finds this while having a similar issue :)