# how to connect model instance in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Code Description**

I have a model called Hospital who is the the user having OneToOne relationship with the user model. the Hospital Model is like a profile for the user.
I have another model called patient which has a Foreginkey relation with the User like a One to many relationship. This means the user model can have many patient.
I have another model called Card which has a OnoToOne relationship with the Patient and a foreignKey relationship with the Usermodel. this means a patient can have one card and that particular card can only belong to one patient and also the card belongs to the hospital not just the patient thats why i added a foreign key to relationship to the user model.
I have another Model called Diagnoses which also have a ForiegnKey relation with the PatientModel and a foreignkey  relationship with the User model because the diagnoses is not just for the patient but also the hospital.
This means a patient has a card, and can have many diagnoses.

**Using this method, successfully, a user can have many patient.
Now my problem is, when a user want to create  a new card or diagnoses for a specific patient, how will a patient be associated with the card or diagnoses, cause there is no field to bind that card nor diagnoses to a patient. The card or diagnoses can be created successfully but no way to select which patient the card or diagnoses belongs to.**

**Heroku link to the hosted version**
https://digirv1.herokuapp.com/

**Code**

**views.py**

```
class PatientListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class PatientDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

# Card Views
class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,  )         
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(hospital=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(hospital=self.request.user)

class PatientCardDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(hospital=self.request.user)


# Diagnoses Views
class PatientDiagnosesListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
    queryset = Diagnoses.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(hospital=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(hospital=self.request.user)

class PatientDiagnosesDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Diagnoses.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(hospital=self.request.user)
```

**models.py**

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default="Hospital Name")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



#hospital created on account verification just with this signals no need for additional config
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Hospital.objects.create(user=instance)
        print("hospital created")

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created == False:
        instance.hospital.save()
        print('hospital updated')

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
class Card(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)    
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Patient, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name         

class Diagnoses(models.Model):
    sickness = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)   
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Patient, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sickness
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PatientListAPIView.as_view(), name="patient"),
    path('<int:id>', views.PatientDetailAPIView.as_view(), name="patient"),
    path('card', views.PatientCardListAPIView.as_view(), name="card"),
    path('card/<int:id>', views.PatientCardDetailAPIView.as_view(), name="card"),
    path('diagnoses', views.PatientDiagnosesListAPIView.as_view(), name="diagnoses"),
    path('diagnoses/<int:id>', views.PatientDiagnosesDetailAPIView.as_view(), name="diagnoses")

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Add foreign key to the models you want patients to access..

Answer (score 0):

First include the Foreign keys in the serializer fields for the DiagnosesSerializer:

```
class PatientsDiagnosesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = Diagnoses
        fields = ['id', 'sickness', 'note', 'owner', 'hospital']
```

Then checkout this post: [Django REST - Create object with foreign key using serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543775/django-rest-create-object-with-foreign-key-using-serializers)
It should address your issue.